# Async not working as expected

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have several files that I need to write to remote server. As you can see in my code, I'm reading those files inside async scope and writing them to remote server as they become available. Instead of all files, only the last file is successfully transfer to remote server. I put console output statement inside readfile callback function and check path variable value. It outputs the last filename three times. So I'm suspecting that the last readfile call is overwriting the previous ones.  Shouldn't async wait for the callback function call before it moves onto next iteration?

```
var attachments = ['1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg'];
var request = require('request');
var option = {
    url: "http://www.xxxxxxx.xxxx",
    headers: {"content-type": "multipart/form-data"}
};      

async.each(attachments, function(att, callback){
    path = imagePath + "\\" + att;
    fstat = fs.statSync(path);
    fsize = fstat["size"];      
    fs.readFile(path, function(err, data){          
        if(err)
        {
            return callback(err);
        }
        else{
            option.body = data;                                     
            request.post(option,function(err,response,body) {
                if (err) {
                    return callback(err);
                }
                else{   
                    console.log(option);
                    callback();                     
                }
            });             
        }   
    });
}, function(err){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("finish");
    }
});
```

Comment: Where is `option` declared? Why are you mangling it each time through the loop?

Comment: I see a lot of errors like almost all the variables are declared somewhere else - `option`, `_path`, etc.. You are using `fs.statSync(_path)`, but `_path` is missing.....

Comment: Sorry guys, I did some redaction before I posted here for easier read and made some mistakes while I was doing. Anyway, I fixed it. Thanks

Comment: You must use `var` as otherwise each variables is declared globally, and is overriden. In your current example, you use `request.post(option`, but first `option` is not guaranteed to have the correct body, and second - the same `request` is used over and over again. I'm sure `console.log(option)` prints the very same body, right?

Comment: Are you saying that filestream and request variable should be declared as local? Yes you are right, option.body has the same body for each iteration. Since my callback call is inside the callback function of post request, shouldn't async wait until that function gets called before moving onto next iteration?

Comment: No, if you read the documentation it says that `each` runs them in `parallel`. Use `eachSeries` instead..

Comment: @Andy Popov: Thanks! You point out that I use the same request object. Since request object is created by calling require('request'), how can I create new request object for each iteration? I looked on the net but seems that deep copy of objects involve extensive codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Shouldn't async wait for the callback function call before it moves onto next iteration?

No, you're describing what [`async.eachSeries`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachseriesarr-iterator-callback) does. [`async.each`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eacharr-iterator-callback) runs each all tasks in *parallel*.

Your problem is that here is only one `option` object here. You perform `console.log(option)` inside of a function asynchronously run by `request.post`. That callback function runs *after* every `request.post` has been run. Since you only have on `option` object, it will have the final `body` value it was assigned by the last `fs.readFile` callback.

The solution here is to have every `each` function call create its own `option` object:

```
async.each(attachments, function(att, callback){

    var option = {
        url: "http://www.xxxxxxx.xxxx",
        headers: {"content-type": "multipart/form-data"}
    };
```

Comment: You are right!!! I was using the wrong method all along. I should have used eachSeries. Thanks!!